# How do online blackjack games shuffle cards?

Tags: random, cryptography, shuffle, blackjack, gambling

What method of shuffling do online blackjack games use? Do they keep a "deck" of cards representation in code, or simply treat each hand as a completely new pick from the set of cards at random?

Comment: Well it wouldn't be blackjack if each hand is completely new, so there would have to be a simulated "shoe" of decks. It is an implementation detail exactly how it is simulated. The most natural thing would be to do a Fisher-Yates shuffle ahead of time, but this is just speculation and hence somewhat opinion-based and also too-broad. While this is an interesting question, I don't think that is really on-topic. Furthermore, your question seems to assume that all sites use the same method. Why should that be true?

Comment: You did not ask for it, but i mention it: they will use (1) external entropy (physical-measurements; maybe site-related timings / user-behaviour although not the latter one alone) (2) cryptoPRNGs. - The rest is dependent on the game; but if shuffling is needed, Fisher-Yates is great (given some random bits).

Comment: Those who do it *correctly* will properly simulate a deck or shoe full of cards with an array, use a good RNG with over 240 bits of state, use reduction sampling to make it uniform over the size of the shoe, plus a proper Fisher-Yates reshuffle when there are about 15% of cards remaining to properly simulate actual casino practice. I'd guess that fewer than 10% of software blackjack games do all of that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot who is the manufacturer of the game and what kind of programming language they use. Imagine that each time you are creating new deck of card objects. Even in this case you will need to shuffle them. Good shuffling algorithms are very important and if the manufacturer is skilled enough it will use algorithm like [this one](https://blog.codinghorror.com/shuffling/):

```
var rand = new Random();
for (int i = cards.Length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    int n = rand.Next(i + 1);
    int temp = cards[i];
    cards[i] = cards[n];
    cards[n] = temp;
}
```